# Google Sheets: How to query a sheet to return distinct equipment ID based on newest entry and sort by condition score column

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking to create a "condition" sheet that displays and sorts descending the most current condition score for each equipment item in my "inspection" sheet, based on the equipment's most recent inspection. I have tried a variety of methods with query and unique and have yet to find the right solution. Any advice or ideas are appreciated.
In my "inspection" sheet the timestamp is A, the equipment ID is D and the condition score is Z.

So far my query is: =query('Inspection'!A:Z,"select A, D, Z Where A is not null Order By Z Desc")

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: @player0 Here is a copy of the data. I am seeking to return the most recent final condition score (row z) for each equipment ID and sort by the condition score descending. Thank you! [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qs-allrt_rNeRtC2ESmZ3qDh05tF5p5gkXmgozExZCg/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

> In the inspection sheet **paste** this, take a look at [**This Sheet.**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dl0e0UYa6f0WdvP4_DaULIspuiiM_URjYq71qHO9DSc/edit?usp=sharing)

```
=QUERY({inspection!A:A,inspection!D:D,inspection!Z:Z}, " Select * where Col1 is not null Order By Col3 Desc ")
```

[image]

### Explanation

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) the Array `{inspection!A:A,inspection!D:D,inspection!Z:Z}` of the ranges A,D and Z and set the query to `" Select * where Col1 is not null Order By Col3 Desc "` Select everything `*` where Col1 is not empty and order Col3 descendingly.